# can Firewall detect vpn that a client use on their pc?

Tags: vpn, firewall

if some client uses vpn program installed on their pc,through a copmany or hotel network with internet connection and firewall, can the firewall detect that vpn connection? what would the firewall show in report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, it will depend on the firewall and the VPC in use.
Firewalls are either Stateless or Stateful.  Stateless firewalls will look at the ports and/or IP addresses used for connections and block or allow connections based on these.
Stateful firewalls will look at the contents of the traffic being exchanged (possibly in concert with the IP addresses and ports) and decide what type of traffic is flowing.
If an organisation has a stateless firewall and chooses to block VPN traffic, they can do so by blocking the ports of well-known firewall protocols.  PPTP typically runs on port 1723, L2TP/IPSec uses UDP ports 500 and 4500 and L2TP without IPSec uses port 1701.
A firewall employing stateful packet inspection can choose to ignore the ports and look at the traffic itself to decide if it is VPN content and then block or allow this based on further rules.

A firewall probably isn't going to do much more than block or allow the traffic, and potentially log why it was blocked or allowed. Intrusion Detection Systems and Intrusion Prevention Systems may go further than this and hold details of the packets that were transferred, while this is separate from the firewall, it is often lumped in with it.

VPN traffic is encrypted, so with a modern strong VPN protocol, your data should be safe.  Older protocols such as PPTP may be subject to security vulnerabilities that could allow traffic to be analysed.

A report from the Firewall is likely to contain the IP address (potentially resolved to a machine name) for the origin and destination of the traffic and origin and destination ports.

Comment: Ok, but firewall shows each client what websites has visited, do you mean that in case of vpn firewall would show the ip Adress used by  vpn program only?

Comment: As we have said, logging activity is not a firewall function (at least not very normally). You can get specialized routers or add ons to routers to log activity but this is not likely to happen. Lots of traffic, few people to look and analyze.

Comment: As John has said in his reply a firewall on it's own is unlikely to be logging by default. Logging every connection attempt will generate a lot of data that most admins will not have the time or inclination to look through.
IF logging was enabled and IF you were just looking at a firewall log and not an IPS log, then I would not expect it to be trying to break the encryption from your VPN to work out where you were trying to connect to with your VPN. In this hypothetical situation, I would expect to see the connection from your machine to the VPN endpoint only.

Answer (score 1):

A firewall like this is only to allow or block connections.

I think you might be unable to make a VPN connection in a hotel or like environment (double NAT causes issues).

Otherwise, if you do succeed in making a connection, the firewall will not evaluate what it is.

It all depends on the connection type (double NAT and firewall blocking) but I think these arrangements are just to secure their facilities, not to evaluate what you are doing if the connection is allowed.

It takes more specialized equipment and people qualified to analyze the output to look at your specific websites and type of VPN gear.